# Why is "/" used for rendering the index page

Tags: javascript, express

I am confused what the "/" is used for in this piece of code:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) =>// The / is a shortcut for index.html (might be right could be wrong)
{
    res.render(index);
});
```

Comment: Try looking at the URL path as an actual file-system path, where `/` is the *root directory*. On Unix and Unix-like systems (for example Linux or macOS) the `/` is the actual file-system root directory, and also acts as directory separator.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional and convenience.

Given the domain `example.com`, you want the homepage to be at `https://example.com/` (i.e. the path, which comes immediately after the domain name, is `/`) so you don't need to type `https://example.com/anything-here`.

Comment: Can you simplify it a little bit

Comment: In this case what is the homepage? is it index? Do you want me to send a bit more of the code so it might be potentially clearer

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the default page of the website, i.e `example.com`, would render the index page.

However if you wish to make a different page, such as `example.com/about` you would use `/about` and render the about page.

e.g. for your code

```
app.get("[Whatever directory]" ...)
{
res.render([whatever page])
...
```

Comment: Can you simplify it a little bit

Comment: In this case what is the homepage? is it index? Do you want me to send a bit more of the code so it might be potentially clearer